# Logging Internal server error in a different log, Symfony2

Tags: php, symfony

I would like to write this kind of errors in a different log than the normal Symfony log. I need to handle and identify this errors to be able to resolve them. Symfony saves by default this exceptions in dev.log or prod.log, but there are a lot of messages mixed in this log. I need to catch only the internal 500 errors.. nothing else.

Comment: Take a look at this: http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/logging/monolog.html

Comment: But how can I separete the 500 internal errors? I just want to log this kind of errors in a another file than prod.log or dev.log, just the 500 internal error, nothing else..

Comment: Read the doc, it's all there. Hint: use different handlers